# Google Earth Engine: what does it mean by mask an image with itself?

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking

I am a newbie and following the GEE tutorial at this link:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_05

I do not understand the following line of code under the section of Mosaicking:

*// Mask water with itself to mask all the zeros (non-water).

water = water.mask(water);*

The water variable on the right hand side of the assignment is a mask that has value 1 for water and 0 for non-water.

Don't you get the exact same mask when applying it to itself? I am completely confused by the above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image's mask is separate from the numerical value. If the mask is 1 (unmasked), the value can still be 0 or 1 (or anything else). Self-masking causes all the 0 values in the image to become masked (no value) instead of 0.